# Updating a recurring payment profile created by express using UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile call

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

On my website I have to plans of $95 and $195 among which user can switch in between a billing cycle.

I am using Paypal Express checkout API to create recurring accounts. But as express checkout has a limitation that only an increment of 20% is allowed within a period of 180days, plan switching is not possible in my website.

My queries are:

1. Is there a way to update to $195 from $95 with Express Checkout
   API?
2. Is there a way to cancel existing account and create a new
   account with increased amount?
3. Can I use UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile() to update details of a recurring
   account created using Express Checkout?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

1)  Updating from $95 to $195 would be more than a 20% increase and would fail.

2)  Yes, you can cancel a profile and create a new one with the new pricing info.  This can be done manually or via the API using [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/).  Then you would create the new one accordingly.

3)  You can, but you won't be able to increase the amount more than 20% like you mentioned.  If that's what you need to do you'll have to cancel and create a new one.

Note that if you were to use Payments Pro to create the profiles instead of Express Checkout there would be no limit on the amount increase.  You can raise as much as you need to as often as you need to.  Payments Pro + Recurring Billing is going to run $50 or $60 per month, though, on top of the transaction fees you'll pay.